# top words used in a column of dataframe r and binary column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
df=  data.frame(
    text= c("test and run", "rest and sleep", "test", "test of course"), 
    id = c('a','b','c','d'))
#            text id
#1   test and run  a
#2 rest and sleep  b
#3           test  c
#4 test of course  d
```

I would like to

1. have a compact way (no loops) to get the top 2 most repeated words in the column text ("test" 3 - "and" 2)
2. create/add a binary column that matches the top 2 values.

```
topTextBinary 
1, 1
0, 1
1, 0
1, 0
```

for "test","and"

```
            text id topTextBinary
1   test and run  a          1, 1
2 rest and sleep  b          0, 1
3           test  c          1, 0
4 test of course  d          1, 0
```

thank you

---

R studio version

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do the following:

```
# Word frequency table
tbl <- table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$text), " ")));

# Top 2 words
top <- tbl[order(tbl, decreasing = T)][1:2];

# Flag top2 words per row
library(tidyverse);
map(names(top), ~ df %>%
    mutate(!!.x := as.numeric(grepl(.x, text)))) %>%
    reduce(left_join)
#Joining, by = c("text", "id")
#            text id test and
#1   test and run  a    1   1
#2 rest and sleep  b    0   1
#3           test  c    1   0
#4 test of course  d    1   0
```

Or `unite` entries from the 2 binary columns into a single column:

```
map(names(top), ~ df %>%
    mutate(!!.x := as.numeric(grepl(.x, text)))) %>%
    reduce(left_join) %>%
    unite(topTextBinary, -(1:2), sep = ", ");
#            text id topTextBinary
#1   test and run  a          1, 1
#2 rest and sleep  b          0, 1
#3           test  c          1, 0
#4 test of course  d          1, 0
```

Comment: wow!! thank you...  i have an hard time understanding the map() function . I also tried and got an error  `Error in map(names(top), ~df %>% mutate(`:=`(!(!.x), as.numeric(grepl(.x,  : 
  unused argument (~df %>% mutate(`:=`(!(!.x), as.numeric(grepl(.x, text)))))`

Comment: No problem @StefaniaAxo `purrr::map` is very similar to base R's `Map`. I cannot reproduce your error. I used your `df` sample data; copy and pasting above code runs without errors. Can you double-check?

Comment: i changed the text with the version of my R studio. The library tidyverse is 1.2.1

Comment: @StefaniaAxo Strange, it works with the same `tidyverse` version on different machines on my end. Can you quit R/RStudio and start from a fresh session (don't save the workspace). Perhaps there is some conflict with other R packages that you are automatically loading. I'm not sure what you mean by *"i changed the text with the version of my R studio"*.

Comment: the comment section here in stackoverflows allows you just few character..i had to put the result of my 'version' command in the original question for space issues

Comment: i restarted as you said and got the same result

Comment: I noticed this message though .....Warning messages:
1: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
2: package ‘readr’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
3: package ‘forcats’ was built under R version 3.4.4

Comment: @StefaniaAxo Those warnings are ok (they occur because the binary version of CRAN packages are based on a more recent R version, but they will still work on your R version); I noticed from your error the part `... mutate(:=(!(!.x), ...`. That looks wrong; it should be `mutate(!!.x := ...)`; can you copy&paste the **exact code** into a fresh R terminal?

Comment: it did not come with the copy and paste and the code section of the comments of stackoverflow...but it is there :-( ...is there another way of doing the same...,maybe another library ..it is exactly what i was looking for though

Comment: `rm(list=ls())` ..you were right something in my workspace...was messing things up  ..now it is working

Comment: Great @StefaniaAxo, glad we got to the bottom of this. You should mark the question as solved by setting the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: question: why does it say `Joining, by = c("text", "id")` ..that left join seems to mess up thing when the dataframe contains much more columns than that...

Comment: @StefaniaAxo I'd recommend going through the commands step-by-step to understand what's going on; `map(...)` produces a `list` of `data.frame`s, which are then joined based on the common columns `test` and `id`. Not sure what you mean by "mess up thing when the dataframe contains much more columns than that". This sounds like a different question. Please close this one, then ask a new question if you have different problem. SO doesn't like extended discussions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Using Base R:

```
top2=names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$text),"\\s"))),T))[1:2]

transform(df,m=paste(grepl(top2[1],text)+0,grepl(top2[2],text)+0,sep=","))
            text id   m
1   test and run  a 1,1
2 rest and sleep  b 0,1
3           test  c 1,0
4 test of course  d 1,0
```

if the aim is to use this for maybe 3,4,or even first top 10 words then you might consider doing something like:

```
transform(df,m=do.call(paste,c(sep=",",data.frame(t(outer(top2,df$text,Vectorize(grepl))+0L)))))
            text id   m
1   test and run  a 1,1
2 rest and sleep  b 0,1
3           test  c 1,0
4 test of course  d 1,0
```